# How to use getIntent() without trigerring other intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to pass data from one `activity` to another one, to do this I use `getIntent()` in the 'second' `activity`. My problem is that I already have an intent that sends the user to the 'second' `activity` when the user clicks on the notification. For some reason now, when I try to get data from another `activity` and call `getIntent()` it triggers the notifcation.
How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can do a trick by adding a boolean extra in your intent from notification :

```
notificationIntent.putExtra("isFromNotification",true);
```

so now that you are in your second activity :

```
boolean isFromNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromNotification",false);
```

and you can now know whether its from notification or not

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Maybe I wasn't clear but my problem is that I have the notificationIntent that open 'second' activity after a set amount of time. That's how it initially worked before I added another intent that sends data to 'second' activity, so now when I click the button to send the data, it automatically opens the 'second' activity! is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I solved the issue using SharedPreference to pass the data from one activity to the 'second' one.

Comment: that's what i was about to say , using sharedPresferences ... glad you solved the problem